# How to add view in UIWindow?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwindow

I wanted to add a view in `UIWindow` with following code:

```
 AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
 UIWindow *window = delegate.window;
 UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
 aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
 [window addSubview:aView];
```

This code didn't work. I wanted to clone property of UIAlertView. It will pop over top of everything when we call
`[alertViewInstance show];` method.

**Tried this as well:**

```
   UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

    if (!window) {
        window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    [window addSubview:aView];
    [window bringSubviewToFront:aView];
```

Comment: set its `rootViewController` and `makeKeyAndVisible`; in your application (after did-finish-lauch!) if you are not using a `UIWindow` like this, that means clearly that you _do not_ need to use `UIWindow` for the actual task.

Answer (score 11):

If are you using `UINavigationController` Use:

```
[self.navigationController.view.window addSubview:aView];
```

If are you using `UITabBarController` Use:

```
[self.tabBarController.view.window addSubview:aView];
```

In `AppDelegate` you can directly assign a view to window. In `appDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method Use:

```
[self.window addSubview:aView];
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 7):

Try with this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    if (!window) {
        window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    aView.center = window.center;
    [window insertSubview:aView aboveSubview:self.view];
    [window bringSubviewToFront:aView];
}
```

Comment: huh? it will work. I use this code to custom(fake) popoverView or alertView. You can add this code bellow: [window bringSubviewToFront:aView];

Comment: My storyboard: http://i.cubeupload.com/fnceNh.png
aView will not show if you do not set rootviewcontroller

Comment: When I'm adding this view it adds successfully!! But My Navigation Bar slightly hides behind this view. Any Suggestion?? @TienLe

Answer (score 6):

Try this code:

```
window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows lastObject];
```

Replace the following code:

```
window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 4):

Your windows needs to have a root view controller.

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

UIWindow *window = delegate.window;
UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; 
window.rootViewController = controller;
UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[controller.view addSubview:aView];
```

Comment: This seems to work but the new view is covering whole screen. It's frame is { (0,0) (320,568) }

Comment: yes the viewcontroller.view covers the whole screen. aView which is the view you want has size 100, 100

Comment: What I wanted to do was make it appear like alertView. Transparent background. But it will overlap the viewController viewController from which this code is called.

Comment: When I'm adding this view it adds successfully!! But My Navigation Bar slightly hides behind this view. Any Suggestion?? @NikosM.

Answer (score 4):

You can add view using the following

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:YOUR_VIEW];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code...for adding subview to window

```
UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:aView];
```

//Removing

```
[aView removeFromSuperview];
```

Hope it helps you..!

Comment: When I'm adding this view it adds successfully!! But My Navigation Bar slightly hides behind this view. Any Suggestion?? @vidhyanand

Answer (score 2):

i think you are missing this. check once.

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: This is it... other methods work so long as you have this

Answer (score 2):

UIAlertView creates another UIWindow and set this window as key window when you call show method. So if you want to show your own alert view create a UIWindow instance show it and add your custom alert view to this newly created window.